# How to implement rollback transaction on SQLite3 database using C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sqlite

I am using open source CppSQLite wrapper in my project to access the SQLIte3 Table,

I am trying to insert  couple of  sql queries to the sqlite3  table. If any of the insert query failed, I need to roll back the transaction.

My code similar to the following:

```
    CppSQLiteDB db;
    db.execDML(L"begin transaction;");
    db.execDML("insert into emp values (7, 'Test7');");
    db.execDML("insert into emp values (8, 'Test8');");
    db.execDML("insert into emp values (9, 'Test9');");
    db.execDML(L"commit transaction;");
```

How can I rollback the transaction if any one of the insert query failed. Should I check the return code of each insert query?

> Reference:
>   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6343/CppSQLite-C-Wrapper-for-SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `execDML` throws an exception when an error occurs, you can use an exception handler:

```
db.execDML("begin");
try {
    db.execDML("insert ...");
    db.execDML("insert ...");
    db.execDML("commit");
} catch (...) {
    db.execDML("rollback");
    throw;
}
```

If it didn't, you would have to write a wrapper function for `execDML` that checks the return code and *does* throw. However, it appears CppSQLite already does this for you.